# Python curses import error: 'from curses import ACS_DARROW, ACS_LARROW, ACS_RARROW, ACS_UARROW' not working

Tags: python, curses

```
  File "C:\Users\a small youtuber idk\Downloads\from curses import ACS_RARROW.py", line 2, in <module>
    from curses import ACS_DARROW, ACS_LARROW, ACS_RARROW, ACS_UARROW
```

i tried importing _curses and curses but nothg is working

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html, you'll see:

```
Note: These are available only after initscr() has been called.
```

The values are different on different operating systems, so the module has to ask the underlying library for the correct values.